# An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ../node_modules/chart.js does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, primeng

I'm trying to use PrimeNG on my Angular project,Iv created a new project and tried to start, but it give me this error, I did the following steps:

1. `npm install primeng --save`
2. `npm install @angular/animations --save`
3. `npm install Chart.js --save`
4. `npm uninstall ng2-charts`

I added `../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js` in my **Angular.json**

When I try to run my project with `ng serve`, it gives me this following error :

> An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ../node_modules/chart.js
>   does not exist

Any help can be usefull, thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is a part of my Angular.json :

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/YarbiTkhdem",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": ["../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"]
          },
```

Comment: We will need more information to help you on that, what is your code? How did you try to import chart.js?

Comment: I did, I didnt write any code, I just tried to start my project after including these libraries...

Comment: Could you please provide the part of the angular.json were you added the library?

Comment: yes sure, Ill edit the question right now

Comment: This didn't work for me.  If I remove it from scripts, the build will compile, but I get a runtime error on my page that "Chart" is not defined.

Comment: @mattforsythe you found any solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need the chartjs script in your angular json

"scripts": ["../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"]

And you can add typing to charjs with :

```
npm install --save @types/chart.js
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chart.js

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, I was following a tutorial, they said that I should include that into my scripts, as u said I just removed `"../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"` from Scripts on my `Angular.json` :)

Comment: Great ,i’m glad to have helped :D

Answer (score 2):

An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js does not exist.

Just install using npm install chart.js --save

The problem will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you have chart.js  already install  you need to make sure that the route is the right one. I don't know why but for me I had two leading dots... i had to remove one of the leading dots and it worked just fine.